# jacorb: Package difference for java files generated from idl

Tags: jacorb

I am trying to generate java files for CosNotifyChannelAdmin.idl provided in jacorb-3.8's ../idl/omg folder.

It has a definition as:

```
interface EventChannel :
      CosNotification::QoSAdmin,
      CosNotification::AdminPropertiesAdmin,
      ....
```

and another definition as:

```
struct AdminLimit {
      CosNotification::PropertyName name;
      CosNotification::PropertyValue value;
   };
```

I observe that java file generated for AdminLimit has package 'org.omg.CosNotifyChannelAdmin', while files generated for EventChannel has package as 'CosNotifyChannelAdmin'.

Why this difference?